# Populate different cells in a column with different values using a "for" loop

Tags: python, for-loop, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to populate the first 9 cells in a first row with different values in an excel spreadhseet. The code as is populates the first 9 cells as expected BUT instead of populating each of the cells with "j" variable string values - "a","b","c","d","e" in each of the cells it populates all 9 cells with only last value - "e". How can I make the code to iterate through the string assigned in "j" and populate the cells in the spreadsheet with each of the string letters?

Python version 3.6, 
IDE: Pycharm

**Here is the code:**

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("test.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
for h in range(0, 9): #Cell position generator
    u = 1
    cell_position = (u + h)
    g = "A"
    f = str(cell_position)
    iterated_cell_position = [g+f]#puts cell positions in a list
    j = "abcde"
    for p in iterated_cell_position:
        for e in j:
            worksheet.write(p, e)
workbook.close()
```

Please help me with this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `iterated_cell_position` is an array of one element, and the line

```
for e in j:
   worksheet.write(p, e)
```

just writes each letter to the same cell. So you write a to the cell, then b to the cell, then c and so on. Try

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("test.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
j = "abcde"
for h in range(0, 9): #Cell position generator
    e = j[h % 5] # gets the correct letter in j (wraps around when h gets too large)
    cell_position = "A{}".format(h + 1)
    worksheet.write(cell_position, e) 
workbook.close()
```